# How to turn 4 cols into 2 cols and 2 rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to achieve like below. On desktop it would show 4 columns and on smaller screens it would break down into 2 columns and 2 rows.

[image]

[image]

How can achieve like above?

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide a different width for smaller screens. The following will lay out the divs as 1 row of four elements wide on lg screens and two rows of two elements per row on smaller screens.Techncally it is one "row" in both instances but two lines with the two elements each in smaller viewports.

What happesns is that each column is a portion of 12 in the viewport - so by designating 3 columns in lg that equates to 3/12 or 25% of the screen real estate - but when the viewport gets down to the md and sm sizes (based on Bootstraps media queries) the width is calclated as 6/12 0r 50% of the screen and the divs that dont go onto one line simply float to the next line.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> Column 1</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> Column 2</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> Column 3</div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> Column 4</div>
</div>
```